# Control the order of keys returned by RegEnumKey

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I wish to create a registry sub-key that will be returned last by [RegEnumKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724861(v=vs.85).aspx)

According to MSDN documentation for [RegEnumKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724861(v=vs.85).aspx) API

> Because subkeys are not ordered, any new subkey will have an arbitrary index. This means that the function may return subkeys in any order.

1. When creating a new sub-key with [RegCreateKeyEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724844(v=vs.85).aspx) or any other API, is there a way to control the index he will get?
2. Is it possible to change the index number of an existing registry key?

Comment: That doesn't sound like the real problem you are trying to tackle, more like your proposed solution. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: What part of 'in any order' don't you understand?

Comment: Even if you coud do this, another application might decide to create its "last" subkey inside the same key, so your subkey stops being the last one. If you need your subkey to be the last one, write a wrapper around `RegEnumKey` that does this (however, you need to recognize your subkeys somewhat). If you wish to hook `RegEnumKey` and hide certain subkeys, hiding ones reported somewhere in the middle is not much harder than hiding the last one (you just enumerate all subkeys, decide which of them need to be hidden and return appropriate information to the caller).

Comment: Another incorrect assumption here is that the keys _in the registry_ have an index. All you can rely on is that the keys _in the enumeration_ have a unique index. Therefore, these questions are meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

> 1.When creating a new sub-key with RegCreateKeyEx or any other API, is there a way to control the index he will get?

No.

> 2.Is it possible to change the index number of an existing registry key?

No.

And the reason for this is very clearly stated in your documentation quote:

> Because **subkeys are not ordered**, any new subkey will have an arbitrary index. This means that the function may **return subkeys in any order**.

There is nothing you can do to control or influence this at the API layer.  If you need to process subkeys in a particular order, you will have to retrieve the subkeys into your own list, then sort that list as needed before processing it.

Answer (score 2):

> I wish to create a registry sub-key that will be returned last by RegEnumKey.

That is impossible to achieve. There is simply no scope for you to control order of enumeration.

Whatever your problem is, you will need to find a different solution.